# Any way to get localized term names in node paths

Tags: uri, tokens, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have a node type "news" with an included term reference field named "newscategory". i18n-module incl. taxonomy-i18n is also installed, vocabulary is translatable and all terms are translated. But for pathauto patterns there is only the token "[node:field_newscategory]" available, which will not be localized depending on the node language.

Is there any trick on achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try Entity Token - it's part of the [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module and provides additional tokens for use with i18n. It will make the token tree item for the term ref field expandable and you should see a token like `node:field_newscategory:i18-name`. This should get you going purely on the UI side.

Although I bet it rocks to be able to wrap one's own piece of code that just works :)

Comment: I would not curse *this* strong ;-) it's not been a wasted time. And after all - you just re-discovered the beauty of http://drupal.stackexchange.com ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after 2 more hours of research and development I've finally managed to get the problem solved. I ended up writing a tiny custom module implementing [hook_pathauto_alias_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7).

The module has several dependencies:

```
dependencies[] = taxonomy
dependencies[] = field_extract
dependencies[] = pathauto
dependencies[] = i18n
dependencies[] = i18n_string
dependencies[] = i18n_taxonomy
```

Here's how I did it (tailored to my special needs, so go on and modify my code)

```
<?php

  /**
   * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter()
   */
  function mymodule_pathauto_alias_alter( &$alias, array &$context ) {
    if ( $context[ 'module' ] == 'node' ) {
      $node = $context[ 'data' ][ 'node' ];
      if ( $node->type == 'news' ) {
        // determine actual context variables
        $language = $context[ 'language' ];
        $pattern = $context[ 'pattern' ];
        $category = field_extract_value( 'node', $node, 'field_newscategory' );

        // translation & preparation
        $category_translated = i18n_string_object_translate( 'taxonomy_term', $category, array( 'langcode' => $language ) );
        $sanitized = pathauto_cleanstring( $category_translated->name, array( 'langcode' => $language ) );

        // re-build the alias
        $alias = explode( '/', $alias );
        $pattern = explode( '/', $pattern );
        foreach ( $pattern AS $index => $part ) {
          if ( $part == '[node:field_newscategory]' ) {
            $alias[ $index ] = $sanitized;
            break;
          }
        }
        $alias = implode( '/', $alias );
      }
    }
  }

?>
```